# p:dataExporter selected rows only

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a `<p:dataTable>` with the multiple selection checkbox. I want to export only some rows to my pdf. Right now when I try to export based on the selected rows it gives me only the rows from the top. For example if I have 10 rows in my datatable and I select 1,4,7,9 to be exported to my PDF. I always get rows 1,2,3,4 in my pdf. I am using the PrimeFaces 5.1 jar. I tried it with 5.2 jar also, Still same issue.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataall"
             var="cars"
             value="#{carsEntry.carssUser}"
             rows="10"
             rowIndexVar="rowId"
             paginator="true"
             rowKey="#{cars}"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
             {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
             {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}
             {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
             editable="true"
             selection="#{carsEntry.selectedRows}">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" exportable="false"/>

    <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{cars.id}">
        <h:outputText value="#{cars.id}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<h:commandLink>
    <h:outputText  value="PDF" />

    <p:dataExporter type="pdf"
                    target="dataall"
                    fileName="AllCars"
                    selectionOnly="true"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Checked these two but still no clear answer.

> http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31804
>   https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7406

Comment: Since you don't post any mcve, the chance that anyone want to even tryto replicate is very low, so please do. Same is truefor just commentig in the PF issue list. It adds nothing. Create a fully working yet minimal example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: added the code for more clarity

Comment: thanks, but this is not an mcve. I cannot run it.

Comment: You will have to use other libraries like iText to export to PDF the selected rows

Comment: I am using iText else I will be getting error in exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my friend Sathish. I was able to find out a work around for this issue. I populate the selected values to a new datatable and export that data. Hence I get the correct values exported. I make rendered="false" for the second data table.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces 5.2 not support generics(List<>), only Arrays ([]). It was fix on Primefaces 5.3.